# Prove a function is continuous in order to show a quotient space in $\mathbb R^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $p: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be defined as $p(x)=0$ for all $x \in \bar B_1(0) := D$ the closed unit ball and $p(x) = \frac{\lVert x \rVert -1}{\lVert x \rVert}x$ for all $x$ outside the ball. Prove $p$ is continous.

I'm trying to prove this in order to show it's a quotient map. So far I've tried proving continuity from definition - taking an open $V \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ and showing there is an open neighborood $x \in U \subseteq p^{-1}(V)$ for all $x \in p^{-1}(V)$.
I divided it to two cases:
If $0 \notin V$ then there exists $r>0$ such that $B_r(p(x)) \subseteq V$. Now I'm trying to find $\delta>0$ such that $x \in B_{\delta}(x) \subseteq p^{-1}(V)$. During my attempt to find such $\delta$, I've managed to show that for $x, y \in \mathbb R^2 - D$ we have $\lVert p(x) - p(y) \rVert \leq \lVert x-y \rVert + \lVert \frac{y}{\lVert y \rVert} - \frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert} \rVert$, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Intuitively I think the distance between the unit vectors should be small since $x,y$ are not in $D$, but I'm not sure how to show this.

Comment: @ronno True! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier to prove sequential continuity. Let $x_n \to x$. If $\|x\|<1$ then $\|x_n\|<1$ for $n$ sufficiently large ange $p(x)=p(x_n)=0$ for such $n$.

If $\|x\|=1$ then we can split natural numbers into the part where $\|x_n\|\leq 1$ amd $\|x_n||>1$  and it is easy to see that both of these subsequences (or the only one if one part has only finitely many positive integers) tend to $0=p(x)$. The case $\|x||>1$ is also easy.

Comment: Ugh once you're done with Calculus and take a Topology course it's like you forget everything you already know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a topological fact you can use which isnt too difficult to verify yourself. If you have finitely many closed sets $A_i$ such that their union is $\mathbb R^2$ (or any topological space for that matter) and continuous functions $f_i:A_i\to\mathbb R$ so that for all $i,j$ we have $f_i|_{A_i\cap A_j}=f_j|_{A_i\cap A_j}$ then the function defined by

$$
f(x,y)=f_i(x,y) \textrm{ where } (x,y)\in A_i
$$

is continuous on $\mathbb R^2$. It's a general result that can be used yo show that these piecewise defined functions are continuous. For the proof, use the fact that a function is continuous iff the preimages of closed sets are closed.